# gconf-tool2 command to set "Place Windows" compiz option?

Tags: compiz, window, gconf

For operational reasons at work, I have access to gconf-tool2 but not CCSM.

Can anyone tell me what the option is called for the purposes of calling gconf-tool2 to set the various "Place Windows"options?

Answer (score 0):

/apps/compiz-1/plugins/place/screen0/options/force_placement_match

Comment: This needs more info. What are the possible settings? Other visitors will find this answer hard to use if it does not include this information.